# Win 10 internet connection is horrible

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, ping, internet-connection

msi b450 gaming plus max board, ryzen 3 3100 cpu, Intel(R) ax200 wifi 6 wireless card

I have tried all the cmd netsch commands, renew ip, full network reset, reseting my router, deleting and reinstalling drivers for the wifi card, but i can't get a stable internet connection, I pinged ipv4 and lost 3/4 packets, pinged ipv4 and lost 1/4, my connection will work perfect for a few minutes randomly and then not work at all for days, the network troubleshooter usually says it cant identify the problem, I am new to this comp stuff, can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should ask on [su] instead.

Comment: Try a new Network card. Try also a new router. You have addressed all the other things that might affect this.

Comment: Can you ping your router or some other local address, to see if your wifi might be the problem, rather than your router / cable modem's connection to your ISP?  Or try a wired connection to your router or even directly to your cable modem.   e.g. ethernet, or some cable modems even support acting as a USB network device.